# getting content from plist to UITableView to details view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, viewcontroller

Im trying to get the label and images of each item in my plist library to show up in my details tab.

Here is a pic of my tableview which i can get my plist dictionary to work. An array of images and an array or items. (ex item 0 is both the thermostat.jpg and Thermostat label.

[image]

Here is a pic of the detail view when clicking on the cell. It pulls the label from the cell and the image of the thermostat.

[image]

However when clicking on item 1 in plist (the toilet) it pulls the toilet name but still shows the thermostat image. Like so.

[image]

Here is my code for detailviewcontroller

the.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemLabel;//Name of that view
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView; //Image View
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myTextView; //Description View

@end
```

and .m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize itemLabel;
@synthesize itemName;
@synthesize myImageView;
@synthesize myTextView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


itemLabel.text = itemName;
//**************SCROLL VIEW*************
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,960)];
scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,90.0,0.0);


////I know below this is the Problem, BUT im not sure what its supposed to be?////
NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle     mainBundle] pathForResource:@"repairlist" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"];
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

So all in all im trying to get the image to correctly show when clicking on that cell

Here is an image of my plist im using:

[image]

I already have this in my TableViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ItemListCell"]) {
    DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView     indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.itemName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    } else {
        indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.itemName = [repairList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //destViewController.textView = [descrip objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please mark this question as solved if you were able to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem,

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

You set your image always the same index which is 0. So, logically, you're always seeing the same image. So, what you need to is that you need to detect which cell was selected before you push `DetailViewController` and pass that info to your `DetailViewController`. Then, you need to use that info to show appropriate image in your `DetailViewController`.

First, you need to declare a property in `DetailViewController.h`,

```
@property int selectedRow;
```

change also this line of code

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

to

```
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedRow]];
```

Then in your `TableViewController.m`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.selectedRow = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i new that that was the problem. I'm not sure what I should change it to. Would seeing the tableview controller h and m files help?

Comment: @Ezcaflowne Are you using Storyboard or nibs?

Comment: I already have that added in my TableViewController, check my edit please. Thank You.